# PhpStorm file too large

Tags: phpstorm

Когда пытаешься открыть файл, который весит больше 20мб, в PhpStorm то программа отказывается открывать его, так как лимит стоит - 20 мб.
В интернете нашел что можно увеличить лимит, но у меня не получилось. Помогите пожалуйста решить проблему, если можно подробней.

Comment: что за файл то? и какая версия phpstorm

Comment: да мне тоже интересно что может быть из кода больше 20Мб

Comment: @teran, .sql файл который весит 21.67М. PhpStorm 2016.3

Comment: @varz62 дак не код, логи или xml, вероятно.

Comment: а как пытались увеличить лимит?

Comment: @teran, добавил в папку `.PhpStorm2016.3` файл `idea.properties` в котором вписал `idea.max.vcs.loaded.size.kb=40960`

Comment: вот [здесь](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/file-idea-properties.html) пробовали `idea.max.intellisense.filesize` менять?

Comment: @teran, сработало но теперь памяти не хватает